# How do I use Fermat's Little Theorem to solve the following:

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$x^{13}$ = 2 mod 23. I know how to use the Fermat's theorem, but in this case, we don't know the value of "a". So I am unsure of how to even start?

Here all I know is that p = 23 and thus $a^{22}$ = 1 mod 23

Comment: What do you mean????????????

Comment: What is the problem to be solved here? Find $x$?

Comment: Yeah it just says to solve the equation

Answer (score 1):

Since $13\times17=221\equiv1\bmod22, $

$x^{13}\equiv2\bmod23\implies x^{13\times17}\equiv x\equiv 2^{17}\bmod 23.$

Comment: Note:  $x^{13\times17}\equiv x$ follows from Fermat's Little Theorem, which says $x^{22}\equiv1\bmod23$; [$2^{11}\equiv1\bmod23$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24169/find-the-remainder-of-211-by-23) so $x\equiv2^6=64\bmod 23$

Comment: So this means $64^{13}$ divided by 23 will give me a remainder of 2?

Comment: @SanchitKumar:  [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=64%5E13+mod+23) is correct

Comment: Ok so is there a formal way you came up with that 17?

Comment: I inverted $13$ modulo $22$

Comment: Oh so just the multiplicative inverse of 13 modulo 22 will result in 17 and then you multiply both sides by $x^{17}$?

Comment: I took both sides to the $17^{th}$ power to get $x$

Comment: So by raising the left side to the 17th power we essentially eliminated the 13th power because 17 is the modulo inverse and we just got x???

Comment: I don't understand how you got 2$^{11}$ power

Comment: Click on the link for that above (in my first comment)

Comment: So how are we supposed to come up with that if we didn't know that before?

Comment: $2^{11}\equiv1\bmod 23$ was not essential to the answer, just a short-cut to calculating the answer $2^{17}\bmod23$

Comment: So without the shortcut, how would we apply Fermat's little theorem to $(2^{17})$

Comment: Fermat’s little theorem was used to prove that $(x^{13})^{17}\equiv x$. There are many posts on this web site explaining how to compute something like $2^{17}\bmod23$

Comment: I think the answer should be 18 and not 64 the answer to $2^{17}$ is 18 not 64

Comment: mod $23$, $18$ and $64$ are the same (I had left reducing $64$ mod $23$ for you to do; note $64=23\times3-5$ and $18=23\times1-5)$

Comment: So what would be the steps on how to solve questions like these? Like for a general case, can you tell me what I would have to do step by step

Comment: if $x^a\equiv c\bmod p$ and $ab\equiv1\bmod p-1$ then $x\equiv c^b\pmod p$

Comment: Oh okay. So what are these types of questions called? $x^a$ = c mod p? So I can learn more about them and also is there another example I may try like this?

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/806684/xn-2mod-13) is a related question